# Mosync: Can a Widget subclass the TimerListener class

Tags: c++, mobile-phones, smartphone

**I know a Moblet object can subclass a timerlistener class but can a Widget also subclass the TimerListener?**

With my code below I am getting an error *`addTimer' was not declared in this scope*:

```
class MyWidget : public QAButton, public TimerListener
// The class QAButton inherits from Label & PointerListener
{
    MyWidget( MAUI::Widget *nParent, QAScreen *nDestinationScreen )
             : Widget( 0, 0, 0, 0, nParent )
    {
        // Constructor:
    }

    void initAnimationTimer()
    {
        // Post:

        addTimer( this, 20, 0 ); // Error here "`addTimer' was not declared in this scope"
    }

    void runTimerEvent()
    {
        // Post:

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

TimerListener is an interface (it has the pure virtual function runTimerEvent) which any class can implement.

You get an error when trying to access addTimer in MyWidget because it is a function of the MAUtil::Environment class. You can access it through the singleton MAUtil::Environment::getDefault().